# ionic 3 passing infromation between tabs. Student

Tags: typescript, ionic3

more or less im trying to get a user to input information into one tab and have them press a button and have the information pushed to the next tab that is a list of people generated from a api a jsonblob, The main problem Im having is that it keeps telling me TypeError: _co.Buttonclick is not a function. Can anyone help or lend a hand.

this is the contacts.ts which is where the person would enter there details.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { EventsPage } from '../events/events';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    }
    public text:string;
    onButtonClick(){
      this.navCtrl.push(EventsPage,{text:this.text});
    }
      ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegisterPage');
      }
         }
```

this is the contact.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Register
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-col width=50>
  <ion-list><ion-item>
    <strong>Registery page :</strong>Upcoming Event
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Name :</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary">Age :</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" placeholder=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">weight :</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Input Weight"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Club :</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Input Club"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Division :</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Input Division"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">YearsExperince :</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Input experince"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>



  </ion-list>
<ion-content padding>
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveUser()"></form>
    <button ion-button (click)="Buttonclick()"> Add Fighter</button>
    <p>
    bla bla lba lb
    </p>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `onButtonClick()` to `ButtonClick()` on your `contacts.ts`. It has to be the same function name that you have used on `contact.html`.